# Upload trix file attachments inserted as html

Tags: javascript, trix

So I'm trying to take already uploaded Trix attachment html and put them into another editor where i want the upload to happen as well.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the

```
editor.insertHTML()
```

instead of just putting the html content inside of it.

Once the HTML is inserted the editor will process the files as if they were just dropped or copy/pasted on to it.